# How can I compare cosine similarity for a list of NDArrays

Tags: deeplearning4j

I have a list of 4 NDArrays in a Java program - I want to compute the cosine similarity among all 4 of the possible combinations i.e. 4C2 total combinations. As an example, if my arrays were A,B,C and D I would want the combinations between A-B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D, and C-D

Is there a way to do this using deeplearning4j or do I need to compute all combinations myself?